# SQL query executes in MySql Workbench, but not in production

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, amazon-rds

SQL query in question:

`SELECT COUNT(suggestedfood.id) AS num_same, suggestedfood.place_id FROM suggestedfood WHERE suggestedfood.group_id=? AND suggestedfood.selected=? AND suggestedfood.removed=? GROUP BY suggestedfood.place_id LIMIT 1`

This query is able to run within MySQL Workbench, but in production it throws this error :

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND suggestedfood.selected=? AND suggestedfood.removed=? GROUP BY suggestedfoo' at line 1`

`MySQL Error code: 1064`

`MySQL State: 42000`

The MySQL server is on AWS RDS, if that helps, and my code running the SQL query is a Java container on Glassfish. Also many other queries are able to run, it's just this one that is giving me troubles.

If anyone can point out a simple mistake of mine that would be great. Or if anyone knows how I can better diagnose this problem, that would be much appreciated.

Edit, here is my Java code, as asked for `group_id is a long`

```
 long numSame = 0L;
 String count = "SELECT COUNT(" + SUGGESTEDFOOD_ID + ") AS num_same, " 
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_PLACEID + " FROM " + SUGGESTEDFOOD
     + " WHERE " + SUGGESTEDFOOD_GROUP_ID + "=? AND "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_SELECTED + "=? AND "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_REMOVED + "=? "
     + "GROUP BY "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_PLACEID  + " LIMIT 1";
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.connection.prepareStatement(count);
 ps.setLong(1, group_id);
 ps.setBoolean(2, true);
 ps.setBoolean(3, false);
 /* Line 607 */ ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(count);
 while (rs.next()) {
     numSame = rs.getLong("num_same");
 }
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND suggestedfood.selected=? AND suggestedfood.Removed=? GROUP BY suggestedfoo' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)
at com.cow10.endpoints.FoodSessionHandler.togglePlace(FoodSessionHandler.java:607)
at com.cow10.endpoints.FoodSessionHandler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.togglePlace(Unknown Source)
at com.cow10.endpoints.FoodWebSocket.handleMessage(FoodWebSocket.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:477)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.access$100(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:87)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint$WholeHandler$1.onMessage(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:573)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusSession.notifyMessageHandlers(TyrusSession.java:542)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onMessage(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:748)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onMessage(TyrusWebSocket.java:200)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.TextFrame.respond(TextFrame.java:135)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:622)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:394)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.onDataAvailable(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.onDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:453)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandler(InputBuffer.java:1101)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandlerOnProperThread(InputBuffer.java:1092)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.append(InputBuffer.java:975)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:271)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]]
```

Comment: Where have you set your parameters?

Comment: You're very likely executing the query wrong, i.e. your **Java code** is flawed, so if you want our help, you need to 1) Show the code, and 2) Show the full stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical mistake.

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(count);
```

should be

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

as `ps` is a `PreparedStatement` extending `Statement`, and `executeQuery(String)` is an unusable Statement method.

*Should one ever create a similar API, override `executeQuery(String)` and make it `@Deprecated` with a nice javadoc.*

Answer (score 0):

The question mark `?` is invalid in the context of that statement; MySQL doesn't see that as a numeric literal, a character string literal, or a valid reference.

We can cause the same error running a simple query like this:

```
SELECT 'abc', 2, ?, NOW()
```

and MySQL returns this error:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '?, NOW()' at line 1
```

---

That question mark character is likely meant to be a placeholder for a bind variable. Without seeing the actual code, we're just guessing... we'd expect to see the SQL text passed as an argument to `prepareStatement`, and then calls to appropriate methods to bind variables to the placeholders, before the execute, e.g.

```
  PreparedSatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqltext);
  ps.setInt(1,groupId);
  ps.setInt(2,selected);
  ps.setInt(3,removed);
```

---

**EDIT**

This answer was posted *before* OP added any Java code in the question. As Joop Eggen's answer points out, it's a simple problem in the (now provided) OP code... the parameter being supplied in the `executeQuery` method. Don't do that for a prepared statement.

Comment: The question mark is not there when the code is being executed that is just in the debug statement from printing the unprepared statement, since I am using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between the = and the ?.

```
String count = "SELECT COUNT(" + SUGGESTEDFOOD_ID + ") AS num_same, " 
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_PLACEID + " FROM " + SUGGESTEDFOOD
     + " WHERE " + SUGGESTEDFOOD_GROUP_ID + "= ? AND "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_SELECTED + "= ? AND "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_REMOVED + "= ? "
     + "GROUP BY "
     + SUGGESTEDFOOD_PLACEID  + " LIMIT 1";
```